# How can i display the username in all the following pages after successful login using html php?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $admin=$_POST['Name'];
    $pass=$_POST['Password'];
    $dummy=0;
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,'');
    mysqli_select_db($con,"package");
    $query="select * from admin where admin_id like '$admin' ";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {   
        $dummy=1;
        if($row['password']=='$pass')
        {
            header("Location:booking.html");
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $admin;
            header("Location:admin_login.php");
        }
    }
    if($dummy==0)
    {
        header("Location:contact.html");
    } 
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my admin login page in php how should i store the username and use it in html?i have used session_start() but dont know how to use this in the html page

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have some errors in your displayed php file, see below for correction:

```
<?php

session_start();
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$admin=$_POST['Name'];
$pass=$_POST['Password'];
$dummy=0;
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,'');
mysqli_select_db($con,"package");
$query="select * from admin where admin_id like '$admin' ";
$sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{   
    $dummy=1;
    if($row['password']=='$pass')
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['admin_id'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $admin;
        header("Location:booking.html");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location:admin_login.php");
        exit();
    }
}
if($dummy==0)
{
    header("Location:contact.html");
    exit();
} 
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**i have fixed below 2 Errors in your code:**

1. You have to write `exit()` after calling `header('location:...')`. Otherwise the script execution will continue, it will not terminate itself.
2. you have to set `$_SESSION['user']` variable  if Username and Password match with database record but you are setting session variable if password don't match, it will not work.

Now you can Display Username in all other pages as below , use same below code in all your other page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || empty($_SESSION["user_id"]) )
{
   header("Location:admin_login.php");
   exit();
}
// if user is authentic then display username
echo " Hello, " . $_SESSION["user"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), a cookie is sent to user, and every page you call session_start() enable you to access the super global $_SESSION.

When your user was authenticated, you can set:

```
$_SESSION["Username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $userid;
```

And at other pages, after started the session, you can use this to check if user was authenticated:

```
if ( ! empty ( $_SESSION["UserID"]))
{
  // User is authenticated
  echo "Welcome back, " . $_SESSION["Username"] . "!";
}
```

All variable added to $_SESSION will be available to future pages when session was started. You don't need to do anything to save this data, PHP will do it automatically when script execution finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Display login user name in all pages.

1. change your all pages extension .html to .php
2. you already set session in your login page i.e  $_SESSION['user'] = $admin;
3. use below code to display session value in all pages.

   ```
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['user'];
   ```

define session_start(); top of the page and echo session value across the page where you want.